# Of "was X and Y" and "was X and was Y," which is correct?

Tags: conjunction-reduction

I sometimes confuse when to use *"to be"* when there are verbs associated with one noun. What is a difference between these two sentences given below:

> 1. A promotional plan was launched and completed.
> 2. A promotional plan was launched and was completed.

Comment: Have you searched for yourself?  If so, please indicate what you found.

Comment: The second is ponderous.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please more elaborate on?

Comment: Hi, Black Death. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), taking care to note the comments on search & research, including: "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Answer (score 1):

Both are "correct" and mean essentially the same thing. The second emphasizes the distinction between "launched" and "completed", which may or may not be desired. It's up to you to decide which you want.

Answer (score -3):

The first sentence is correct. In the second sentence the verbs are connected with "and" so you don't need to write "was" twice.

Comment: Does that mean the second sentence is wrong? Or is it just redundant (but not wrong)?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's grammatically wrong, but I would strongly recommend always using the first one.